# Why is calling Tohru amazing an insult to her?

Tags: fruits-basket

In the first episode of the new show, after learning more about Tohru's life, Yuki says she's amazing. In response Shigure tells him it's an insult to call her that.

Yuki agrees, but I frankly didn't understand what they meant by that.

Comment: because calling Tohru "amazing" is an understatement. IMO, Shigure thinks Tohru is beyond amazing.